# Understanding List.fold_left and implementing insertion sort using it

Tags: algorithm, scala, functional-programming, ocaml

I'm trying to learn OCaml, and I'm still struggling a bit with the fold functions. I've done a bit of research and I've found the following code snippet (written in Scala) implementing insertion sort using foldleft. I think I get the idea, but I know absolutely nothing about Scala, so I still need a bit of clarification. So, I guess my question is 2-fold (ha, get it?), how would this function be written in Ocaml, and how does it actually work?

```
def insertionSort[A <% Ordered[A]](list: List[A]): List[A] =
  list.foldLeft(List[A]()) { (r,c) =>
    val (front, back) = r.span(_ < c)
    front ::: c :: back
  }
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Assuming I understand this code, it looks like a worst-case quadratic sort to me.  It repeatedly looks down the list for the spot to insert each new element.  If input is already sorted in reverse order it has to go to the end each time, which is roughly n * n / 2.

Comment: I understand that this is horribly inefficient as an actual sort function. But it was presented as, and I'm asking about it, in terms of an exercise demonstrating folding.

Comment: In terms of understanding folding, I think implementing a SUM function using fold is a better example than sort.

Comment: @Chasemedallion: Unfortunately, a lot of people, when taught fold using sums, seem to think that's the *only* thing they are good for. However, fold is *universal*: *everything* you could possibly do with iteration can be done with a fold. Rúnar Óli Bjarnason gives  a very nice explanation in his [Functional Programming for Beginners](http://Vimeo.Com/18554216/) talk.

Comment: @JörgWMittag: Agreed. However, given this universality, why use an algorithm whose primary function is as a straw man for more efficient sorts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I commented above, this isn't a particularly nice way to sort (assuming I understand the Scala code, which I might not).  Here is an OCaml translation of what it seems to be doing:

```
let insertion_sort l =
    let add1 sortedl x =
        let le, gt = List.partition ((>=) x) sortedl
        in
            le @ [x] @ gt
    in      
        List.fold_left add1 [] l
```

After you write FP code for a while, folds become quite natural.  The purpose is to process a series of elements from a data structure (e.g., a list) in a known order (e.g., leftmost first), while maintaining some state that gets passed along as you do your processing.  In the simplest cases (as here), the state is also your final answer.  In other cases, you need to carry some extra state along with the final answer.  In those cases you extract the final answer at the end.

Maybe I shouldn't say this, but a fold is like the `for(;;)` statement in the C family, except that it encapsulates all the state that you plan to modify in your loop.  In this way, it's a nicely controlled form of iteration.

The correspondence looks something like this:

```
for(state = S, x = first(D); more(D); x = next(D)) { state = E(state, x) }

fold_left (fun state x -> E state x) S D
```

The discipline of encapsulating the modified state usually turns out to be incredibly helpful after you get used to it.  Very often the function that you fold (like add1 above) turns out to be useful in many other circumstances, because the structure of the fold requires a generally useful function in that spot.

Note that, in particular, the fold function contains all the knowledge of how to traverse the data structure.  The folded function only needs to know about what to do with each element.  So you are free to change the data structure (and the fold) without changing any of the other code.  And you can also use the same folded function (`add1` above) with different data structures.

Comment: Scala has both `partition` and `span`, but I don't know their correspondence to OCaml. In the algorithm above, `span` will only put on `front` the leftmost entries that are less than `c`. Any entry after the first one that doesn't match the predicate will be put on `back`. Other than that, the translation seems ok.

Comment: Well, I think the list (partially computed answer) is always sorted.  So the leftmost enties less than c are the only entries less than c.  In other words, `span` and `partition` will always get the same answer in this computation.  But `span` may be slightly more efficient because it doesn't have to traverse to the end of the list in every case.  The OCaml `partition` function will always look at the whole list.  (Doesn't affect the worst case, but `span` is likely faster on average.)

Answer (score 0):

```
let insertion_sort (l: int list) : int list = 
  let rec insert (e: int) (a: int list) =
    match a with
    | [] -> e::a 
    | h::t -> if (e > h) then e::a else h::(insert e t)
  in 
  List.rev (List.fold_left (fun a e -> insert e a) [] l)
```

List.fold_left takes in a function, an accumulator, and a list.
The accumulator should be initialized as an empty list [], so that when List.fold_left receives an empty list as the 'l' argument, it will return an empty list since there is nothing to sort.

(fun a e -> insert e a) updates the accumulator. As List.fold_left folds through the list, it takes each element and inserts it into the correct position of the sorted list. The helper function let rec insert performs this job.

```
let rec insert (e: int) (a: int list) =
  match a with
  | [] -> e::a 
  | h::t -> if (e > h) then e::a else h::(insert e t)
```

It first sees if the sorted list is  empty. If it is, then it inserts the element into the empty list. Else (the sorted list is not empty), then it compares the element to be inserted with the head of the sorted list, and recursively checks to find the sorted position of the element in the sorted list.

Finally, List.rev is called because the insert function uses the cons operator (::) which appends an element to the front of the list. Therefore, the final list must be reversed.